# Grabbing status updates via WebApi and AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to determine the best/reliable way to configure my angular application so that I can submit requests to a webapi, and periodically check the progress of the logic running on the server.

Making the api calls isn't in question, determining a way for angular to grab status updates is my main question here.

Upon calling the initial api, do I setup a timer that periodically calls a different API method that is able to see and return the status?

I'm open to any ideas/solutions

Comment: use web sockets..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go that route, but I believe the answer is [*SignalR*](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

At the end of the day, you send a request to an API and you're also subscribed to a notification channel to get updates, and the server can publish message to the whole channel.